# Override Elasticsearch _type in Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I was wondering if it is possible to set the `_type` field on the Elasticsearch document using an annotation on the entity class. I am currently using `hibernate-search-orm` and `hibernate-elasticsearch` version `5.8.2.Final`.

Adding the `@Indexed(name="my-index-name")` annotation allows me to target a specific index. However, the document type is always the Class name. If the project is ever organized in a different way the type would not match the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do what you want at the moment.

If you change the organization of your project (e.g. moving packages around or changing a class name), you will have to reindex your data.

Using the class name is a good way to be sure we won't have conflicts in the names.

I will add it to the things we have to discuss for Search 6 and see if we want to act on this.

Comment: Thanks! I think it would be a nice feature.

Comment: Yup, sending a mail to hibernate-dev right now to see what others think about it and if we should open an issue for it. I'll post the issue here for reference if we open one.

Comment: Cool, just sent one over.