# How to configure type name or filter by type query with Elasticsearch integration?

Tags: hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search with Elasticsearch integration with the versions 5.8.2 and 5.6 respectively.

Let's say I have 2 applications which use the same database and I want to search for `Person` entity. Both of the applications will update indexes but only one of them will read.

Since, by default Hibernate Search uses fully qualified class names for `type`s, I end up with 2 different types for the same entity like:

`Person` -> `com.example.x.Person`

`Person` -> `com.example.y.Person`

In the application I'm performing the search, while constructing the search query, Hibernate Search automatically add `filter` query for `type` like:

```
"filter": {
    "type": {"value": "com.example.x.Person"}
}
```

thus search results don't contain the records from `com.example.y.Person` type.

Is there any way that I can customize type names?

Or, is there any way to disable/customize added `filter` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it for now.

Funnily enough, we just had a very similar question a few days ago: [Override Elasticsearch _type in Hibernate Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107499/override-elasticsearch-type-in-hibernate-search/47160930#47160930) .

My advice is the following: if it's the exact same entity, you should extract it in a common jar and use the same entity in both of your applications (if you cannot extract it, you can still use the same package but I would recommend to extract it so that you're sure it's exactly the same).

Comment: nice coincidence :) ok, I got it. what about the constructed query, I guess there is no way to customize or disable `filter` query, right?

Comment: No you can't disable it. You could use the Elasticsearch client directly to target the index but I wouldn't recommend that. Frankly, you'd be better sharing your classes between the 2 applications.

Comment: @sedooe it's great feedback, we'll see how to deal better with this in future version of Hibernate Search. Thanks!

Comment: I thank you both! by the way, let me drop this [link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1044995&e=0) about something which makes me really wonder, hope to get an answer to it when you have time :)